# Where is the question that I can put this answer about sexual and rebirth?

Tags: support

The question that I answer for has deleted. However, I think this answer still useful. So I searching for the question that match with my answer.

> You need to recite paṭiccasamuppāda-pāli & ariyasacca-pāli. Everything
>   perfectly and completely taught in tipitaka.
>
> Rebirth (jāti, upattibhava) depend on avijjā & **taṇhā** (upādāna) &
>   **kamma** (3 saṅkhāra, kammabhava).
>
> 3 taṇhā = kāmataṇhā, **bhavataṇhā**, vibhavataṇhā (sacca-pabba).
>
> Whatever is **good kāma/bhava/vibhava** (piyarupaṃ, sātarūpaṃ) such as
>   beautiful nun, is what is attached by
>   kāmataṇhā/bhavataṇhā/vibhavataṇhā such as you love to sense about
>   nun/you love to be a nun/you love to leave your male faculties
>   (purisindriya).
>
> Bhavataṇhā cause of **kamma**, so the example cases are:
>
> 1. Your love (kāmataṇhā) to sense (kammabhava) about nun, will cause a male rebirth.
> 2. Your love (bhavataṇhā) to be (upattibhava) a nun, will cause a female rebirth.
> 3. you love (vibhavataṇhā) to leave (upattibhava that cause of the other difference kind of upattibhava) your male faculties, will cause
>      a female rebirth, that is difference kind of male rebirth.
>
> You can receive bad effects in every sex, so tipitaka and commentary
>   never specify the sex as an effects of kamma, except when the sex is a
>   very significant cause of good/bad effects, such as
>   purisindriya/itthindriya. For the example, a woman must release blood
>   every month, so a **regular** woman often week more than a **regular**
>   man, in physical body. So in **regular** case, female rebirth is
>   suffering more than male rebirth.
>
> However, that example doesn't mean that tipitaka of commentary specify
>   the sex as an effects of kamma. That example is just an effect of
>   kamma-bhava that depend on taṇhā. So, if male in the example has an
>   enough strong taṇhā, he will not rebirth as a woman, but he can
>   rebirth as a bloody man instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The question that I answer for has deleted.**

Yes, its author deleted it.

Comment: I don't care the deleted answer. I just finding the question about sex and rebirth to place my answer. I have searched, but I didn't found. What kind of keyword I should to use for searching.

Comment: Are you saying you don't care about the deleted question, but that instead you want to find and answer any other different older question about gender and rebirth?

Comment: There is [According to Buddhism, how can a woman get a male soul?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/20384/254) although I'm not sure that's about rebirth. There is [Gender : Is it truly what it seems?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13687/254) but that's a downvoted question and tagged anatta rather than rebirth. There's [Karma of Birth?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/12789/254) but that's not specifically about gender. And probably many more...

Comment: To search question I add `is:question` to the search, as explained in the [Advanced Search Options](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/searching). So for example https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+kamma+gender

Comment: That search find [Is gender a result of Kamma?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3274/254) which might be just what you're looking for.